# C# Call an app using the command line

Tags: c#, c++, command-line, argv, argc

In my C++ App, which is an `.exe`, I have this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
--argc;
++argv;
if (argc != 1){
    throw std::exception("Bad command line.");
}
```

E.t.c

But how would I call that in my C# (WPF) app? I tried `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("pathofapp.exe", "stringiwantedtouse")`, but I got `Bad Command Line`. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using the c++ program like this:

```
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    if (argc != 1){
        throw std::exception("Bad command line.");
    }
}
```

And then use argv[0] to access it's first parameter.

For example:

In C++:

```
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    if (argc != 1){
        throw std::exception("Bad command line.");
    }else{
        std::cout << "Param 1: " << argv[0] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

In C#:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("pathofapp.exe", "this");
```

Output:

```
Param 1: this
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("pathofapp.exe", "stringiwantedtouse")
```